# Errors importing MatTreeModule

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm trying to import MatTreeModule.

I've tried,
`import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material';`
and I get the error,

> Module '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTreeModule'.

I've also tried,
`import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';`
and I get the error,

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/tree' in '/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/src/app'

Any recommendations?

My app.module.ts:

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { masterFirebaseConfig } from './api-keys';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { YoutubeComponent } from './youtube/youtube.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { NewMatchComponent } from './new-match/new-match.component';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { TestDbComponent } from './test-db/test-db.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { MatchDisplayComponent } from './match-display/match-display.component';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { TextTransformationService } from './text-transformation.service';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProtectionGuard } from './protection.guard';
import { AllMatchesComponent } from './all-matches/all-matches.component';
import { AnnotationDisplayComponent } from './annotation-display/annotation-display.component';
import { D3Service } from './d3.service';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { UserStatusReportComponent } from './user-status-report/user-status-report.component';
import { PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent } from './payment-or-annotation-details/payment-or-annotation-details.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
// import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
// import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';


export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: masterFirebaseConfig.apiKey,
  authDomain: masterFirebaseConfig.authDomain,
  databaseURL: masterFirebaseConfig.databaseURL,
  storageBucket: masterFirebaseConfig.storageBucket
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YoutubeComponent,
    NewMatchComponent,
    CreateAccountComponent,
    TestDbComponent,
    LandingComponent,
    MatchDisplayComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AllMatchesComponent,
    AnnotationDisplayComponent,
    NotfoundComponent,
    UserStatusReportComponent,
    PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterializeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTreeModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthorizationService, DatabaseService, ProtectionGuard, D3Service, ValidationService, TextTransformationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "data-jitsu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.7",
    "@types/youtube": "0.0.29",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "0.0.41",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/d3": "^4.13.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try updating the version of material

From

```
@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
```

To

```
"@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
```

and do a **`npm install`**

Comment: Seems to have gotten rid of that error, but broken a few other things, e.g.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts(15,17): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Comment: Everyone seems to be recommending reverting back to an older version:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10034

Comment: Update: this has taken me on quite the version updating adventure. Related SO question I've asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128911/error-ts2339-property-takeuntil-does-not-exist-on-type-observablefoo-and

Comment: I'll follow up here once progress is made on the other question.