# error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable<Foo>' and other rxjs v.6 errors

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I just recently updated A LOT of packages in my angular project.

Old package.json:

```
{
  "name": "data-jitsu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.7",
    "@types/youtube": "0.0.29",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "0.0.41",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/d3": "^4.13.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

New package.json:

```
{
  "name": "data-jitsu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/youtube": "^0.0.29",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "0.0.41",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/d3": "^4.13.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` using the new package.json updates and then `ng serve`, I get many compilation errors:

> ERROR in src/app/all-matches/all-matches.component.ts(35,39): error
>   TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'. src/app/app.component.ts(28,39): error TS2339:
>   Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(19,41): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(29,37): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(42,39): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(66,39): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(74,37): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/authorization.service.ts(82,39): error TS2339: Property 'of'
>   does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/database.service.ts(7,31): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
>   src/app/database.service.ts(7,55): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseObjectObservable'.
>   src/app/match-display/match-display.component.ts(27,49): error TS2339:
>   Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'.
>   src/app/new-match/new-match.component.ts(10,30): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
>   src/app/new-match/new-match.component.ts(10,54): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseObjectObservable'.
>   src/app/new-match/new-match.component.ts(130,37): error TS2339:
>   Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable'.
>   src/app/protection.guard.ts(14,34): error TS2339: Property 'map' does
>   not exist on type 'Observable'.
>   src/app/test-db/test-db.component.ts(7,30): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
>   src/app/test-db/test-db.component.ts(7,54): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/mf/Desktop/dataJitsu/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FirebaseObjectObservable'.
>   src/app/user-status-report/user-status-report.component.ts(28,39):
>   error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.
>   src/app/user-status-report/user-status-report.component.ts(33,45):
>   error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type
>   'AngularFireObject<{}>'.
>   src/app/user-status-report/user-status-report.component.ts(35,56):
>   error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type
>   'AngularFireObject<{}>'.
>   src/app/user-status-report/user-status-report.component.ts(43,66):
>   error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type
>   'AngularFireObject<{}>'.

Most of these errors seemed like they had to do with rxjs, and I think rightly so because I'm using rxjs v.6 in the update, and my understanding is that many things were broken between v.5 and v.6.

I played around with installing rxjs-compat
`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`, and I can confirm that this package, in addition to being a hefty addition, does not resolve any of the errors I'm seeing.

I also automated some of the updating by running ts-lint, per the advice [here](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/) and [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration):

```
npm i -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p [path/to/tsconfig.json]
```

I get the following message:

> No valid rules have been specified for JavaScript files

I'm guessing this means that I didn't use proper ts conventions when using rxjs?

I'm still pretty incompetent when it comes to rxjs, so it's not clear to me exactly what else needs to be refactored.

But I think that my issue actually occurs before the refactoring can of worms:

I took a look at the first error (the

> error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable'

one). The error came from a method in my authentication service. In the import statements at the top of this service (and most of the other .ts files, for that matter), my IDE is highlighted a lot of, "cannot find module foo" errors (e.g., "cannot find module, 'rxjs'" for the import statement, `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`).

Similar errors in the same file:

`import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';` ("Cannot find module, "@angular/core")

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` ("Cannot find module, "firebase/app)

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';` ("Cannot find module, "@angular/router")

Here's my app.module.ts file, in case that's useful:

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { masterFirebaseConfig } from './api-keys';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { YoutubeComponent } from './youtube/youtube.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { NewMatchComponent } from './new-match/new-match.component';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { TestDbComponent } from './test-db/test-db.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { MatchDisplayComponent } from './match-display/match-display.component';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { TextTransformationService } from './text-transformation.service';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProtectionGuard } from './protection.guard';
import { AllMatchesComponent } from './all-matches/all-matches.component';
import { AnnotationDisplayComponent } from './annotation-display/annotation-display.component';
import { D3Service } from './d3.service';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { UserStatusReportComponent } from './user-status-report/user-status-report.component';
import { PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent } from './payment-or-annotation-details/payment-or-annotation-details.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
// import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';


export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: masterFirebaseConfig.apiKey,
  authDomain: masterFirebaseConfig.authDomain,
  databaseURL: masterFirebaseConfig.databaseURL,
  storageBucket: masterFirebaseConfig.storageBucket
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YoutubeComponent,
    NewMatchComponent,
    CreateAccountComponent,
    TestDbComponent,
    LandingComponent,
    MatchDisplayComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AllMatchesComponent,
    AnnotationDisplayComponent,
    NotfoundComponent,
    UserStatusReportComponent,
    PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterializeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTreeModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthorizationService, DatabaseService, ProtectionGuard, D3Service, ValidationService, TextTransformationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here's the branch of the repo containing all of these issues.

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu.git
cd dataJitsu
git checkout version-hell-SO 
npm install
ng serve
```

Any troubleshooting hints or outright solutions to the importing issues are welcome and encouraged!

Comment: Just add import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like your operators are still chained in rxjs 5.x fashion.

So to recap what changed in rxjs6 :

1. Imports are different. Now, you should import Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject etc. AND methods that were in 'rxjs/add/observable' differently. So all of these must be imported from 'rxjs'. For example :

   `import {Observable, Subject, of, from} from 'rxjs'`;

   Alternatively, all operators like map, concat, do (which now is called tap) etc. are to be imported from `rxjs/operators`. so something like :

   `import { map, tap, takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';`

   **I think your imports are pretty sane.**
2. You must use pipes instead of chaining your operators.
   For instance, in your all-matches.components.ts, line 33, if you replace :
   `this.authService.getCurrentUser().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(user=>{`

   by

   `this.authService.getCurrentUser().pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(user=>{`

   your takeUntil error will disappear.

   In the same fashion, instead of `Observable.of(true)`, you should import of operator and use `of(true)`.

   You can try this in your authorization.service.ts file. All the "of errors" will be fixed.

   **maybe you should inspect this**
3. Concerning the import errors regarding custom files, please check the files actually exist. For example :

   `ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(6,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module './api-keys'`

   related to

   `import { masterFirebaseConfig } from './api-keys'`

   is normal, since this file './api-keys' doesn't exist. 
   PS: maybe you don't have these errors if keys are not stored in git, if so ignore this.
4. Finally, about AngularFire5.0, you should use one of the operators :

   `Db.list('items').subscribe(console.log)`

   becomes (with valueChanges method) :

   `Db.list<Item>('items').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log)`

   More info : 
   https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Sorry about the missing API key file. I intentionally gitignored it so that it wasn't publicly accessible.